# how to set selected option in jquery multiselect

Tags: jquery, jsp, select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I use jquery multiselect. I want set option selected but when I write *selected="selected"* attribute into option then multiselect doesn't run correctly. For example when two option is selected then I deselect this option after this the number of selected doesnt decrease. I use *Control 6: With callback* in [this demo](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/).

**My javascript:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#identificationMethods").multiSelect( null, function(el) {
    ...
  });
});
```

**My HTML**

```
<select id="identificationMethods" name="identificationMethods[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100px;">
  <c:forEach items="${identificationMethodICs}" var="im">
    <option <c:if test="${im.selected == true}">selected="selected"</c:if> value="${im.subType}">
      ${im.subType}
    </option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: can you do a fiddle? maybe also the generated html would be helpfull

Comment: Control 6 is the same select which I use. http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/